# What roles does decay of intensity of light play in Double slit experiment?

Tags: waves, interference

Today I read that the *Intensity* of a *point source* of sound is inversely proportional to square of radial distance.

My question is during the Young double-slit experiment we get a **uniform** fringe pattern, but as there are 2 point source of light,

the intensity decrease with radial distance and thus the point at larger distance from central maxima should be less brigher.

Why is this not observed in real experiment?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most double-slit experiments take place in the far-field regime. This means that, the distance from the slits to the screen is much greater than the lateral range being examined,

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://cnx.org/contents/hy7Siss-@1/Youngs-Double-Slit-Experiment)</sup>

that is, that $x\gg |y|$. In this regime, the inverse-square decay in the amplitude can mostly be neglected.

If you *do* care about the drop in the illumination from each of the point sources, you normally need to care about the specific shape of your sources (i.e. they're never actually point sources), and the regions they illuminate, before you actually need to care about anything as drastic as an inverse-square decay.

However, if you're only looking at the pattern for a limited $|y|$ which is smaller than both the slits-to-screen separation and the characteristic length on the screen  of the variations in the illumination of each source, then it's a reasonable first approximation to think of the slits as point sources.